# Localhost is taking abnormally long time to load any page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, latency

The logs don't show anything different, and the computer is four times faster than the last one. Anyone know any common reasons why making a request to localhost would take a very long time?

I am using Mongrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give a solution based on the little information you give, so try to narrow it down. I would say that these three causes seem the most likely:

- the database is slow. You can check this if your queries take a long time (check the logs). Perhaps you are using a slow connector (i.e. the default Ruby MySQL library), or your indexes haven't made it to your new machine.
- Mongrel is slow. Check by starting it with Webrick and see if that's any better
- your computer is slow. Perhaps it's running something else that's taking up CPU or memory. See your performance monitor (application to use for this differs per OS).

Comment: Ha! Turns out I was running parallels! FMC

Answer (score 0):

Could be a conflict between IPv4 and IPv6. If you're running Apache you have to take special steps to make it work nicely with IPv6 (my information here might be out of date.) I've found that an IPv6-enabled client would try to talk IPv6 to the server, and Apache would not receive the request. After it timed out the client would retry on IPv4.